# What is the purpose of types/react and types/react-dom libraries in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am working with react 18 in typescript. However, apart from react and react-dom, I also see types/react and types/react-dom libraries in package.json. What is the purpose of these libraries?

Answer (score 1):

The ones with @types prefix are type declaration packages.

- Some libraries are now including the types in the library for you.
  Couldn't find the types file for Axios, simply because they have
  already provided the types, no need for an extra types file.
- @types/react and @types/react-dom are optional, and are not needed to
  use React or TypeScript. If you are not using TypeScript in your
  project, or if you are satisfied with the type inference provided by
  the TypeScript compiler, you may not need to install these packages.

Comment: Does this mean that @types/react-dom also include react-dom? So its just add extra  information so it can be used by typescript?

Comment: @starking The @types/react-dom package provides TypeScript type definitions for the react-dom library. It does not include the react-dom library itself. You still need to separately install and include the react-dom library in your project, but installing @types/react-dom will provide type information that enables TypeScript to understand and type-check the usage of the react-dom library in your code. So yes, it adds extra information for TypeScript to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is most commonly found in React Typescript. As in Typescript, we have to define types of variables. So when we use React with Typescript, we use types/react to declare the type of the React library and types/react-dom to declare the type of the React-dom library.